# Configuring Search Core Results Web Part for Current Site

Tags: search-results

I'm configuring a Search Core Results Web Part to return a list of Webs. I want my the results to be constrained to the current web down. So far I have the fixed query set to ContentClass:STS_Web but this returns all webs for the whole site collection (maybe web application but they mean the same thing here).

What do I need to include to restrict search results to the current site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `path:"http://webapp/site" AND ContentClass:STS_Web`?

Comment: "path" was the property I didn't locate.